# Failed to fetch Spotify repository while updating ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, updates, spotify

Given I have spotify installed on my ubuntu system
When i upgrade using:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then I get this error:

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 13B00F1FD2C19886

W: Failed to fetch http://repository.spotify.com/dists/stable/InRelease  

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Do you have some more questions, or want to set one answer as solution?

Answer (score 32):

This happen when somehow we'd lost the keys.

In order to solve it, I did execute the first step listed in the [official installation guide](https://www.spotify.com/de/download/linux/), inside the section *Debian / Ubuntu*

Comment: You didn't loose the keys, they changed them. https://community.spotify.com/t5/Help-Desktop-Linux-Windows-Web/Linux-users-important-update/td-p/1157534

Comment: In case it complains with `gpg: failed to start the dirmngr '/usr/bin/dirmngr': No such file or directory` try running `sudo apt install dirmngr`

Comment: Agree, adding the newer keys (Jul 2021) took care of preceisely the  NO_PUBKEY error message:
curl -sS https://download.spotify.com/debian/pubkey_0D811D58.gpg | sudo apt-key add -

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Basically what you can do is handle it through Y-PPA-Manager. So please follow exact steps,

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager` to add webupd8 repository.
2. `sudo apt update`
3. `sudo apt install y-ppa-manager`
4. `y-ppa-manager` to run the **y-ppa-manager**.
5. Click on **Advanced**.
6. Click on **Try to import all missing GPG keys** and click Ok. It will give you an alert when it's over.
7. `apt update`

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly enough I started to get this error in 2020.
I've fixed it by running those commands that are provided on their website.

```
curl -sS https://download.spotify.com/debian/pubkey_0D811D58.gpg | sudo apt-key add - 
echo "deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install spotify-client
```

or if you are using snap:

```
snap install spotify
```

Commands found here:
https://www.spotify.com/de/download/linux/